# Append text in json response

Tags: c#, json, append

I am receiving following message in JSON format in my variable `responseString`

```
{
  "CreateCustomerResponse": {
    "ServiceContextType": {
      "Status": {
        "Code": "EI7",
        "MessageType": "ERROR",
        "Message": "Email Oops! Looks like you've already created an account. Please <a href='/account'>click here to sign in.</a>"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I want to replace the received `href` value with `https://www.myweb.com/signin/`. Is it possible?

```
 string responseString = client.POST(relativeURL, createCustomerRequest, contentType);
 responseString = //Replace /account with `https://www.myweb.com/signin/`
```

Comment: yes it's possible. probably pattern matching using regular expressions would be easiest. You might want to deserialize the JSON string first, or it may not matter.

Comment: I think the most reliable method is to deserialize the string to an object, the modify the object's property to what you want.

Comment: @YonF Advice noted. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it using regex like this:

```
string responseString = client.POST(relativeURL, createCustomerRequest, contentType);
string replace = "https://www.myweb.com/signin/";

string result = Regex.Replace(responseString, @"href='(.*?)'", $"href='{replace}'");

// => ...href='https://www.myweb.com/signin/'>click here to sign in.</a>...
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use String functions replace(), replaceAll() etc.
in this way like :

```
String responseString = client.POST(relativeURL, createCustomerRequest, contentType);
String responseStringReplaced=responseString.replace("/account","https://www.myweb.com/signin/");
```